# App services on azure seems to be very slow

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to track down when our frontend started to work that slow. Recently I created new app services within the same service plan.

so now I have six apps (2 frontend, 4 backend) running under same App Service plan using Basic pricing tier. Also, we use Kudu for deployments.

Could that be the reason? or how to look for the reason?

this is overview of that service plan
[image]

appreciating any ideas and suggestions

Comment: what do you mean by slow?

Comment: loading all the requests takes forever, but when I try them using postman they seem to be fast

Comment: If it works with postman you are accessing the same service right?

Comment: 6 apps seems like quite a lot of apps for a Basic tier plan 

Comment: @Sajeetharan right

Comment: @juunas so too many instances can degrade performance right? how many would be okay to run on same plan?

Comment: The CPU on that plan is maxxed out at 100%....I'd start by trying to diagnose/identify if there is a particularly CPU-heavy workload running. You could have 1 app running that could max out the CPU if there's a bug (e.g. infinite loop), is inefficient, or has a higher level of load. Or it could just be because you have a number of apps running that are receiving a lot of work where no individual operation is particularly problematic. Impossible to tell from the info, but I'd be digging into the operations/App Insights

Comment: @AdaTheDev could background job worker also be the reason? In the backend we have several background workers that process the data. but they are not working all the time, only when new files are uploaded

Comment: @user122222 Definitely could be. It's a case of trying to pinpoint if there is a specific code issue, or whether it's just you've hit the ceiling of performance with the current plan level

Comment: So if we just recently noticed that it became very slow (we had 3 services and then added additional three), most probably it's insufficient plan resources?

Comment: through metrics you can identify which app is the culprit here, use the CPU\Processor metric and then apply splitting by apps then you will know which app is the one which is causing this. I would also be recommending using Application Insights to get more insights based on APM based data app insights collect.

Answer (score 1):

@user122222 This is a high CPU issue and not a slow request issue as others have pointed out.

An immediate action you can take is to scale up. If you are using a B1 instance in the basic tier, try to scale up to a B3, which will provide you with more CPU cores and RAM. See if that provides you relief. If so, then you likely need to remain at this instance level. At this point it would also be worth while to analyze your number of requests. You should scale up when you are running many sites or resource intensive sites and you should scale out when you are receiving a high number of requests.

My money is on the fact that you likely have an issue with your code that is causing a deadlock or similar. Your CPU usage graph is stuck at 100% usage over many hours. Even an overloaded ASP will see a few dips over the course of a few hours.

To troubleshoot high CPU usage, start by using the [*diagnose and solve problems* blade](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-diagnostics) in your app service plan. This is the same troubleshooting tool that a support engineer would use in a paid technical support case. Use it to troubleshoot high CPU (not slow requests as based on your screenshot, it would appear the CPU is the culprit of the slow requests).

This can tell you what app in the ASP is causing the issue and sometimes even tell you the process in that app that is causing the issue. Beyond this, I'd suggest creating and analyzing a memory dump of the problematic web app. More steps on how to do that [here](http://jsandersblog.azurewebsites.net/2020/01/02/how-to-get-and-analyze-a-memory-dump-azure-app-services/).

Answer (score 0):

Please try to restart the worker instance.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/app-service-plans/reboot-worker#code-try-0